# Connecting a remote touchpad to an Android system

Tags: android, mouse-cursor, touchpad

I am thinking of connecting a remote touchpad to an android system (via infrared, bluetooth ...), for example for tablets or phones. But I don't know if it is possible to edit Android system in order to do that, or if there are already systems using the concept. I have seen articles talking about using android screen as a touchpad, but what I want to do is the opposite : using a touchpad to move a mouse cursor in an android system.

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Interested on this as well. In particular I need to use my phone (Android 4.2.2) as a touchpad of a android media box (Android 2.3.4) connected to my TV.